# Kindly, create alternative of grave accent based formatting?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

[Grave Accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) isn't a common character, so I fail to find it on many mobile keyboards like SwiftKey (Android). Can I have an alternative character in place of grave accent?

I am not requesting to replace it with new character because thousands of users are used to of it. I am requesting to create alias of it so that another character could also produce the same formatting output.

Comment: I've had the same problem myself.  There usually isn't a back tic on mobile keyboards...

Comment: There is one on iPhones. Tap and hold the `'` single quote button.

Comment: There's one on my droid keyboard also

Comment: It was on my previous keyboard (A.I. Type) too. After SwiftKey update with Flow, I switched to it again (Interestingly, I dropped it because of the SE's same thing)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you can always drop back to plain ol' HTML... Instead of `` `code` ``, use `<code>code</code>` for `code`.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the code. Wouldn't it smash the semantics?

Comment: If you're using that character for anything other than code formatting, you're already smashing the semantics.

Comment: Oh, I see.. :) But, it's not just me, I have seen it in culture on some SE site. BTW, why is it even allowed on non-tech SE sites?

Comment: @SachinShekhar  It's just regular markdown.  It would be confusing to limit markdown to only what certain people think is needed, not to mention that some sites (like [Chess beta](http://chess.stackexchange.com/)) use it for other purposes.

Comment: @SachinShekhar If you look at the page source, Markdown literally just turns \`code\` into <code> tags.

Comment: Some users seem to use it for just plain highlighting (as opposed to marking things typed into a computer). I cannot fathom why they seem to want to do this, as it reduces the readability of their text.

Comment: I'm using grave accent key for pop-up linux console and I'm looking for the ways now to remap this important key somewhere else!